# Error when converting image using domtoimage library

Tags: javascript, dom-to-image

I am using domtoimage library to convert SVG element to blob. I am getting the below error. How to troubleshoot what is the error.

```
function download1(){
            alert('one');
            console.log('Inside Image Blob Creation Flow');
            const svg = document.getElementById("graphContainer").children[0];
            console.log(svg);
            var options = { "cacheBust":true }
            domtoimage.toBlob(svg,options).then(function (blob) {
                console.log('Blob Generated');
                console.log(blob);
                //window.saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
            }).catch(err =>  {
              console.log('Failed to Create Blob');
              console.log(err);
              alert(err);
            });
        };
```

[image]